Why is the request body undefined?
I'm building a simple blog app using Express.js, and I've encountered an issue with the POST request body being undefined when I try to log it in the console:
console.log(req.body) // undefined
This is the code for my server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const jsonfile = require("jsonfile");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const file = "./db/blogs.json";

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.listen(PORT);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await jsonfile.readFile(file);
    res.render("index.ejs", { title: "Home", blogs: data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).render("sr.ejs", { title: "Server Error" });
  }
});

app.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  res.render("new.ejs", { title: "Create New Blog" });
});

///////////////
app.post("/new-blog/", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body) // undefined
  try {
    const blog = {
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      content: req.body.content,
    };
    const data = await jsonfile.readFile(file);
    data.push(blog);
    await jsonfile.writeFile(file, data);
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).render("sr.ejs", { title: "Server Error" });
  }
});
///////////////

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about.ejs", { title: "About Us" });
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.render("nf.ejs", { title: "Page Not Found" });
});

process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log("UNCAUGHT ERROR:", err);
  process.exit(1);
});

I don't see any problems in the HTML either:
<main class="form-container">
    <form action="/new-blog/" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input
          id="author"
          name="author"
          type="text"
          placeholder="bobby8"
          required
          autocomplete="off"
        >
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input
          id="title"
          name="title"
          type="text"
          placeholder="My Favorite Movie"
          required
          autocomplete="off"
        >
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea
          id="content"
          name="content"
          type="text"
          placeholder="It has to be..."
          required
          autocomplete="off"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Post Blog</button>
    </form>
  </main>

The app doesn't crash, but submitting more blogs just pushes more empty objects into the blogs.json file. I've already included body-parser middleware to parse JSON data, so I'm not sure what's causing this issue.
Any suggestions on how to fix this small bug? Thanks!
Edit: Code is here - https://notepad.link/code/QAAbZenzG5KvX8C6Yg2J

<form> elements by themselves don’t create JSON-formatted request bodies; can you share the code where you create a JSON request body and submit to the server?

From other tutorials there wasn't any code that generated the json objects, but I created a post-form.js file to handle that. The problem is that now there are conflicts when sending the post request, and I think it is sent twice when the button is clicked because the json is broken: "So let's harness the power of productivity and unleash our full potential."
},
{}
]
// tle":"wdw","author":"ddwd","content":"dwdwd"}]

Ok, great - however if you’re trapping the submit event and don’t invoke preventDefault() your form will likely POST its data as a normal HTML form would before your fetch can be invoked or its request fully processed. Have you tried adding e.preventDefault() to that handler? What happened when you did?

Adding e.preventDefault() fixes the whole data aspect completely, the only problem is the redirecting to the home page "/" doesn't work anymore (window.location.href = '/' also doesn't work). I uploaded the code in case you want to see it

make sure you add
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

so you can get hold of the data.
check here for further explanation

app.use(bodyParser.json()); is telling express to expect request body in json format. In your view, the form is sending data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default) so I suspect you just have to remove that configuration or post data in json format with your form.

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
